# Short $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the continuity of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Goal: Prove $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ with only the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

I know this is proved in a lot of places, but almost all of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ style proofs are identical (i.e., the chosen $\delta$ is always the same).  The common proof's long-windedness makes me skeptical of my own short proof.  Can someone spot the error?

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

If $c \in (0,\infty)$, then $|\frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{x}| < \epsilon$ whenever $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ where $\delta = \frac{c^2\epsilon}{1+c\epsilon}$.  This follows from the fact that $|\frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{x}| = \frac{|c-x|}{|cx|} < \frac{\delta}{c(c-\delta)} = \epsilon$.

Am I overlooking something?  The usual proof makes sense to me too, but I can't convince myself that it is entirely necessary.

Comment: Because $|c-x| < \delta$, and $|cx| \ge c |x|$, and $|x| > c-\delta$ because it's in the specified interval.

Comment: Since $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$, $|c-x|$ is less than $\delta$.  Additionally, $c(c-\delta) < cx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is right. To prove the continuity of $x \mapsto \frac 1x$ for all $c>0$, it more or less boils down to finding a lower bound on $|cx|$ independent of $x$ (that is, in terms of $\delta$ and $c$). An alternative method of bounding $|cx|$ is choosing $\delta < \frac c2$ so that $x > \frac c2$. This implies

$$\frac{|x-c|}{|cx|} < \frac{2\delta}{c^2} < \epsilon$$

Hence choose $0 <\delta < \min \left(\frac{c^2\epsilon}{2}, \frac c2\right)$

What you did is recognize that, *regardless* of our $\delta$, we always have $x > c - \delta$. So we can entirely ignore the whole $\frac c2$ thing; replacing $x$ with $c-\delta$ and $|x-c|$ with $\delta$ naturally leads to the desired inequality.

Comment: Yes, that is the $\delta$ I saw in every proof I could find online.  Thanks for the reassurance.